# Sharing session between Laravel and PHP App

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have two app in one server, the first is Laravel based and the second is a pure PHP app.

Now I want to save some variables in the session in laravel and use it in my pure PHP app.

I tried various ways to store session variables but any of them won't worked.

```
Session::put('key', 'value');

$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';
```

None of the above storing method allowed me to fetch the session in my pure PHP app.
I `print_r($_SESSION)` this in pure PHP app and return null.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the same session for two apps. Use shared DB or Redis or API to share the data between apps.

Comment: Why don't you implement your logic into laravel app?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan because its an old app and I want to add new features in laravel

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not use the Session to save its sessions, it uses, file, cookie, redis or other drives, which is why you can not access directly in $ _SESSION.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#configuration

Comment: so how can I use `$_SESSION` in laravel?

Comment: You must to use global helper to work with sessions:

// Saving value.
session()->put('key', 'value');

// Gettinng value.
session('key');

Comment: If you are writing an external session to Laravel and want to use it inside Laravel, then you need to use the $ _SESSION itself. If you are using the Laravel helpers, this data can only be accessed within it.

Comment: You don't know any way to use this data in other app?

Comment: You can use other drives such as Redis or database to share session data.

Comment: You can also create another implementation of the Session Drive and customize it so that it uses $ _SESSION. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#adding-custom-session-drivers

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot using `session_start()` before use `$_SESSION`. Please try it.

Comment: No, I didn't forget. I placed `session_start()` in first line of code

Comment: I think you need to define your key with `$_SESSION` variable.